# Windows 10 Mobile keep soft keyboard hidden but then be able to manually show it

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows 10 UWP app running on mobile. I have some text box controls that I do NOT want to show the soft keyboard when they receive focus by default. There is a very good reason for this, it is because there is a barcode scanner that enters data in the field for us. So, I want the user to select to put focus in the field and then it will be populated by another event from the barcode scanner. There is no need to show the soft keyboard in this case and it is majority of the cases. However, there may be a need for whatever reason (the barcode scanner not working right on a particular barcode, etc...) that they will manually need to key in the data. In this case, I do want to show the soft keyboard. So, what I was thinking was to set this property on the text box:

```
tbTracking.PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus = false;
```

or

```
PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="True"
```

This will prevent it from showing when I give programmatic focus but it still shows when they select it.

So, then I tried this code to ignore the text box and use the border around the text box:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="brdTracking" Background="Transparent" Tapped="BrdTracking_OnTapped" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" DoubleTapped="BrdTracking_OnDoubleTapped" Holding="BrdTracking_OnHolding">
   <TextBox Name="tbTracking" PlaceholderText="Tracking Number" PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

With this, I thought that in code I could set the field to have focus programmatically on single click and given the preventing of showing the keyboard on programmatic focus, the keyboard would not show...this is what I want and is all good/working.

However, when I do want to show it, this is where I am having an issue. I thought I could either double tap or hold and that will then show the keyboard. I think while this gives me what I need, it is a nice feature. But, I cannot get it working. I have tried two things in the event handler for hold and/or double tap.

I first tried to force keyboard focus to show the keyboard but this did not work.

```
    private void BrdTracking_OnDoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbTracking.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    }
```

I then tried to disable to programmatic focus setting, set focus and then re-enable the setting but this did not work either.

```
    private void BrdTracking_OnHolding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbTracking.PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus = false;
        tbTracking.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        tbTracking.PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus = true;
    }
```

So, to summarize, my main question is how do I force show the soft keyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [InputPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane) class to show the soft keyboard:

```
InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryShow();
```

Comment: This sort of works. This does show the keyboard like I want but two things that are not desirable happen. First is the keyboard popping up takes focus away from the field that I just held or double clicked on to get the keyboard to show. So, now, after the keyboard shows, I have to select the field again to type. Second is the keyboard is now very difficult to dismiss. If I click on nothing in the background typically, the keyboard will go away since you don't have focus in any fields but with this solution, the keyboard stays showing when I click away.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to reconsider the page layout? What if you use a button to get the barcode scanner data, while using the textbox to populate it with this data and as an input control?